# What are some intermediate level projects to try?

Tags: c++, projects

What are some intermediate level projects that include the use of Templates, Inheritance, STL should one try to learn their real use? I've read about them in the books but it just don't seem very interesting and it is easily forgettable stuff for me.

Comment: http://projecteuler.net/

Comment: IMHO You should try to write something *you* care about, that way you will keep yourself thinking and working. For any semi-big project using things like STL, templates, inheritance etc. will come naturally or you can force yourself to use them to find out where and why they work.